# Customise invoices with dynamic images through API

Tags: quickbooks, invoices

I'm evaluating the opportunity to integrate QuickBooks in a software I'm developing, but I've a question I'm not able to answer just looking at the dev site.

Is it possible to include/attach dynamic images to invoices? I mean:

1. the user creates an invoice
2. an external endpoint is called (webhook to my app)
3. my app updates the invoice with a custom image
4. the user sends or prints the invoice that includes my image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the QuickBooks APIs don't support anything close to what you're asking for.